# html jquery ui bounce effect to a td text

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a baounce effect to a table  like:

```
$('#td-3').toggle( "bounce", 1000 );
```

But it is breaking my table design.
Is there any way that td height should remain constant and only its text bounces.

```
<input type="hidden" name="srno_0" id="srno-0">
<input type="hidden" name="srno_1" id="srno-1">
<input type="hidden" name="srno_2" id="srno-2">
<table>
<tr id="tr-0" class="tr">
    <td id="td-0-1"></td>
    <td id="td-0-2"></td>
    <td id="td-0-3"><span></span></td>
    <td><marquee id="td-0-5"></marquee></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr-1" class="tr">
    <td id="td-1-1"></td>
    <td id="td-1-2"></td>
    <td id="td-1-3"><span></span></td>
    <td><marquee id="td-1-5"></marquee></td>
</tr>...........
</table>
```

And ajax request which is automatically sending in every 10 seconds is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "screen_ajax.php",
    data:dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        $.each(result.tabledata, function( index, value ) {
            if (value['status'] == 1) {
                $('#td-'+value['id']+'-2').html(value['no']);
                $('#td-'+value['id']+'-3').html(value['type'] );
                $('#td-'+value['id']+'-5').html(value['name']);
               if ($('#srno-'+value['id']).val() != value['sr_no']) 
                 {
                    $('#td-'+value['id']+'-3').effect( "bounce", 1000 );
                }
                $('#srno-'+value['id']).val(value['sr_no']);
            }
        });
    }
 })
```

Comment: share your complete code

Comment: i have edited my question please check

Comment: use `animate()` function and toggle `visibility` or `opacity` property since it maintain its space

Comment: @KuldeepThakur: what do you expect from this? http://jsbin.com/rusubocaga/edit?html,output seems i didnt get what do you really want

Comment: i want that only text part should bounce